# Remove values from ranking

Tags: excel, rank

I have some ranking problem in excel. I have list of sales that belongs to salesman and  I want to rank them by looking at sales volume.But issue is I do not want to include David in the sales order.

As you can see, I want to see 'New Rank'.I tried combined functions such as 'Rank&countif' or 'sumproduct' etc. but couldn' handle with that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this in C3 and copy down:

```
=IF(A3<>"David",COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>David",B:B,">=" &B3),0)
```

[image]